# Angular: Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions

Tags: angular, angular16

I'm encountering an issue with my Angular project's tsconfig.json configuration after upgrading to Angular 16. I have the following tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

on npm start I have this error:  Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions
tried to change tsconfig and add types [node] but didn't work

Comment: I removed `typeRoots` to make it work